# 'Using' operand of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient' must implement 'System.IDisposable' - (.NET 3.5)

Tags: .net, vb.net, idisposable, smtpclient

I have a requirement where I need to convert .NET 4.0 project to .NET 3.5 project, 
Everything else is fine except the "SmtpClient"
So far, I have found that .NET 3.5 SmtpClient does not implement IDisposable, while in .NET 4.0 it does!

Below is the code which works fine on .NET4.0 but not on .NET3.5:

```
Using MailServer As New SmtpClient(MailServerName)
MailServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(MailServerUserName, MailServerPassword)
SendMail(MailServer, msgBody, msgSubject, FromEmail, ToEmail)
End Using
```

Any idea how to do it using .NET 3.5 (I prefer to use "Using" code block to auto dispose the object & not the old style manual dispose)

Comment: If SmtpClient doesn't implement IDisposable in v 3.5, then what is there to dispose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a `TryCast` to `IDisposable` before the `Using`:

```
Dim MailServer As New SmtpClient(MailServerName)
Using TryCast(MailServer, IDisposable)
    MailServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(MailServerUserName, MailServerPassword)
    SendMail(MailServer, msgBody, msgSubject, FromEmail, ToEmail)
End Using
```

If running in .NET 4.0, the `TryCast()` returns the `SmtpClient` because it implements IDisposable.

If running in .NET 3.5, the `TryCast()` returns `Nothing` and the `Using` is ignored.

There does not appear to be any cleanup required for `SmtpClient` in .NET 3.5, since they didn't provide a `Dispose()` or any other cleanup method as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hah, I just did posted the answer with same logic. Look at the code. It's exact same. Strange! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that tends to happen a lot on this site. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write the equivalent of the Using statement explicitly.  Like this:

```
    Dim MailServer As New SmtpClient(MailServerName)
    Try
        '' etc..
    Finally
        Dim disp = TryCast(MailServer, IDisposable)
        If disp IsNot Nothing Then disp.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: Which is quite similar to the old way of writing MailServer.Dispose() mannually. Is there no way I can still utilize 'Using' code block to auto dispose the mail client?

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me (with .NET 3.5):

```
Dim MailServer = New SmtpClient(MailServerName)
Using TryCast(MailServer, IDisposable)
    MailServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(MailServerUserName,MailServerPassword)
    SendMail(MonthlyMailServer, msgBody, msgSubject, FromEmail, ToEmail)
End Using
```